# Asymptotics of $\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-k}^{k}\exp{\left[i\sqrt{k^2-\alpha^2}y+i\alpha(x-\xi)\right]}d\alpha$

Tags: integration, asymptotics

I would like to find a leading term for an asymptotic expansion of

$\displaystyle \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-k}^{k}\exp{\left[i\sqrt{k^2-\alpha^2}y+i\alpha(x-\xi)\right]}d\alpha \tag*{}$

as $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\to\infty$ which arose when solving a PDE with domain $(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}\times [0,\infty)$.

**My attempt**
We, firstly, consider what should be the correct solution by a somewhat shady approach.

This problem arose when calculating the Fourier inverse transform of $e^{-yS}$ where $S=\sqrt{\alpha^2-k^2}$. According to P13, 3.39 of *Tables of Fourier Transforms and Fourier Transforms of Distributions* by Fritz Oberhettinger, a similar integral was calculated as below:

$\displaystyle \int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-y\sqrt{k^2+\alpha^2}}\cos{\alpha s}d\alpha= ky s^{-1}K_{1}(ks)$

where $K_1$ is, I am assuming, is modified Bessel equation of the second kind.  Since our function $e^{-Sy}$ is an even function, the Fourier inverse transform can be written with $\cos$, which gives the integral of the above from. Replacing $k\mapsto ik$, we get

$\displaystyle \int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-y\sqrt{-k^2+\alpha^2}}\cos{\alpha s}d\alpha= iky s^{-1}K_{1}(iks)$

We note $K_n(x)=\frac{1}{2}\pi i^{n+1}H_n^{(1)}(ix)$ as seen [here](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ModifiedBesselFunctionoftheSecondKind.html) where $H_n^{(1)}$ is a Hankel function of the first kind, so $K_{1}(iks)=-\frac{1}{2}\pi H_{1}^{(1)}(-ks)$, and since $H_{1}^(1)$ is an odd function, we have $K_{1}(iks)=\frac{1}{2} \pi H_{1}^{(1)}(ks)$. Thus,

$\displaystyle \int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-y\sqrt{-k^2+\alpha^2}}\cos{\alpha s}d\alpha= \frac{iky\pi}{2s} H_{1}^{(1)}(ks)$

By using the asymptotic behavior of Hankel function,

$\displaystyle \int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-y\sqrt{-k^2+\alpha^2}}\cos{\alpha s}d\alpha \sim \frac{iky\pi}{2s}\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi k s}}e^{i(ks-\frac{3\pi}{4})} = \frac{y}{2s}\sqrt{\frac{2\pi k}{s}} e^{i(ks-\frac{\pi}{4})}$

Our integral is the case $s=x-\xi$, and later we use the polar coordinate $x-\xi=r\cos{\theta}$ and $y=r\sin{\theta}$($0<\theta<\pi$). Substituitng the polar coordinate, we obtain

$\displaystyle \frac{r\sin{\theta}}{2r \cos{\theta}}\sqrt{\frac{2\pi k}{r\cos{\theta}}}e^{i(kx-\frac{\pi}{4})} = \frac{\sin{\theta}}{2(\cos{\theta})^{3/2}} \sqrt{\frac{2\pi k}{r}}e^{i(kr\cos{\theta}-\frac{\pi}{4})}$

We are aiming to get this solution (times $2$ because of evenness).

Now we will actually solve the problem. We will use the method of stationary phase.

Applying the substitution $x-\xi=r\cos{\theta},y=r\sin{\theta}$, the integral becomes

$\displaystyle \int_{-k}^{k}\exp{\left[ir\left\{\sqrt{k^2-\alpha^2}\sin{\theta}+i\alpha \cos{\theta}\right\}\right]}d\alpha\tag*{}$

Consider the phase function $h(\alpha)=\sqrt{r^2-\alpha^2}\sin{\theta}+\alpha \cos{\theta}$. This is the same one from [Asymptotics of $\int_{-k}^{k} \frac{\sin{(\alpha R)}}{\alpha \sqrt{k^2-\alpha^2}}e^{ir(\sqrt{k^2-\alpha^2}\sin{\theta}+\alpha \cos{\theta})}d\alpha$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4412944/asymptotics-of-int-kk-frac-sin-alpha-r-alpha-sqrtk2-alpha2) , so by the same method, we have

$\displaystyle \int_{-k}^{k}\exp{\left[i\sqrt{k^2-\alpha^2}y+i\alpha(x-\xi)\right]}d\alpha \sim e^{ikr} \sqrt{\frac{2\pi k \sin^2{\theta}}{r}}e^{-i\pi/4} \\ \displaystyle = \sin{\theta}\sqrt{\frac{2\pi k}{r}}e^{i(kr-\frac{\pi}{4})} \tag*{}$

which looks different from what we should have. We don't have $\cos{\theta}$ at all.

I am guessing the polar substitution was wrong, but I am not sure what to do in that case.

Any idea on why those two do not match?

Comment: hmmm, isn't there a problem with a branchpoint at $\alpha=\pm k$ in your first attempt? i think you should get more something similar to $ \int_k^{\infty}d \alpha \sin(y\sqrt{\alpha^2-k^2})\cos(\alpha s)$ due to jump across the branch cut. 
I am just look and guess, so i might be off a bit, but in principle this is what happens.

Comment: @asgeige True, but I guess for large enough $\alpha$, the integrand would be very small, so I should probably use the integration range $[0,k]$. Here I have defined $\sqrt{\alpha^2-k^2}=-i\sqrt{k^2-\alpha^2}$ for $\alpha\in [-k, k]$.